# Upload file to Google Site. Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sites

I try to upload file to my 'mysitename' Google Site. I using this script, but it does not work

```
function doGet(e) {

  var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle("Upload");
  var formContent = app.createVerticalPanel();
  formContent.add(app.createFileUpload().setName('thefile'));
  formContent.add(app.createSubmitButton());
  var form = app.createFormPanel();
  form.add(formContent);
  app.add(form);
  return app;
}

function doPost(e) {
  try{
  var fileBlob = e.parameter.thefile;
  var pages = SitesApp.getSite('site', 'mysitename').getChildren();
  var attachments = pages[0].getAttachments();
  attachments[0].setFrom(fileBlob);
  }catch(e){
    Logger.log(e.message);
  }
}
```

I catch error "Cannot call method "setFrom" of undefined" last modal window "Error encountered: An unexpected error occurred"

It's works! But i do not know, how to use this circular from documentation "Sets the data, content type, and name of this attachment from a Blob. Throws an exception for web attachments." What is mean this "Throws an exception for web attachments"? I'll be forced to use "try-catch-exception"

Pls, help me to do it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the error is in the line

```
var pages = SitesApp.getSite('sites', 'mysitename').getChildren();
```

The documentation says

> method getSite(domain, name) 
>   Gets the site with the given domain and name. 
>   Use "site" as the domain for consumer sites.

So, if you are within  a domain, use the name of your domain, otherwise use 'site' instead of 'sites'

Comment: Thanks Srik. I catch a new error "Cannot call method "setFrom" of undefined" last modal window "Error encountered: An unexpected error occurred" :(

Comment: It's works! But i do not know, how to use this circular from documentation "Sets the data, content type, and name of this attachment from a Blob. Throws an exception for web attachments." What is mean this "Throws an exception for web attachments"? I'll be forced to use "try-catch-exception"